# Topo-to-Raster Error 010277: Too many points in the contour polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, anudem

The contour lines/shapefile I input to topo-to-raster are producing 'Error 010277: Too many points in the contour polyline".

The T2R outline here under the section ["Use of Contour Data"](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/how-topo-to-raster-works.htm) says "... a maximum of 100 data points are read from the contours within each cell...".

Would anyone know how I could find out approximately how many data points I currently have per cell for the contours lines shapefile?  I have access to ArcGIS Pro, ArcGIS Desktop v. 10.3.1 and QGIS.

Comment: Use ArcGIS's Simplify Line tool to reduce the number of vertices in each topo line.

Comment: Thanks @Bjorn.  I just need to know how many points there currently are, if you have any advice about this it would be very welcome.